# scripted_metric aggregation: map_script and combine_script not invoked

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I am just getting started with ElasticSearch (v1.5) `scripted_metric` aggregations and already stumbled while trying the [example aggregation from the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html).

After I found out how to [access the elasticsearch logger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27981891/1006823) from within a script, it turned out that only `init_script` and `reduce_script` are invoked, while `map_script` and `combine_script` are omitted, even after reducing the scripts to mere logging.

```
[...]
  "aggs": {
    "test": {
      "scripted_metric": {
            "init_script" : "import  org.elasticsearch.common.logging.*; ESLogger logger=ESLoggerFactory.getLogger('myscript');logger.error('1')",
            "map_script" : "import  org.elasticsearch.common.logging.*; ESLogger logger=ESLoggerFactory.getLogger('myscript');logger.error('2')", 
            "combine_script" : "import  org.elasticsearch.common.logging.*; ESLogger logger=ESLoggerFactory.getLogger('myscript');logger.error('3')",
            "reduce_script" : "import  org.elasticsearch.common.logging.*; ESLogger logger=ESLoggerFactory.getLogger('myscript');logger.error('4')"
      }
    }
  }
[...]
```

logs

```
[2015-08-04 08:31:31,841][ERROR][myscript                 ] 1
[2015-08-04 08:31:31,841][ERROR][myscript                 ] 1
[2015-08-04 08:31:31,843][ERROR][myscript                 ] 1
[2015-08-04 08:31:31,844][ERROR][myscript                 ] 1
[2015-08-04 08:31:31,845][ERROR][myscript                 ] 1
[2015-08-04 08:31:32,020][ERROR][myscript                 ] 4
```

Previously, I had started with a slightly modified version of the doc example:

```
[...]
  "aggs": {
    "test": {
      "scripted_metric": {
         "init_script" : "_agg['transactions'] = []",
            "map_script" : "_agg.transactions.add(2)", 
            "combine_script" : "profit = 0; for (t in _agg.transactions) { profit += t }; return profit",
            "reduce_script" : "profit = 0; for (a in _aggs) { profit += a }; return profit"
      }
    }
  }
[...]
```

which fails with a `ReduceSearchPhaseException` caused by

```
[Ambiguous method overloading for method java.lang.Integer#plus.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
    [class java.lang.Character]
    [class java.lang.String]
    [class java.lang.Number]]
```

This happens because in `reduce_script` the `_aggs` array consists of five `null`s, which totally makes sense if `map_script` and `combine_script` do not run.

But why don't they run? Any ideas for digging deeper are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens if a too restrictive filter applies so that no documents are found. In my case, a `bool` filter hid above the fold in my Postman, it took some time before I realized that - sorry, what a silly mistake :-/

Obviously, there's nothing to `map` and `combine` in an empty search result.