# Elasticsearch: Unable to import logger (answer applies to other imports)

Tags: logging, elasticsearch

**Objective**

To use Elasticsearch's logger functionality to better debug server-side Groovy script code.

**Problem Summary**

Unable to import `org.elasticsearch.common.logging.*`

**Details**

- Using Elasticsearch 2.3
- Scripts stored in `/etc/elasticsearch/scripts` and Java client has been able to access them successfully via `Client.update()`. That is, the folder location should be correct. I've seen suggestions to place code in `elasticsearch/config/scripts`, which actually didn't work for me)
- Tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981832/access-logger-from-elasticsearch-script/27981891#27981891), that is:

  `import org.elasticsearch.common.logging.*`
  `ESLogger logger = ESLoggerFactory.getLogger('myscript')`

  But the Elasticsearch log shows a compiler complaint: 
  `unable to resolve class org.elasticsearch.common.logging.ESLogger`

I checked the source code on GitHub [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/0f00c14afc8428a2a72c0b766d2171029dc8f6e1/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/logging) and the ESLogger class is there. So I don't know why this is happening.

Does anyone have advice on getting the `import` to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this is the [Java Security Manager that has been enabled in Elasticsearch 2.2 for scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/float.html#_scripting_and_security). Which means you need to follow the rules and [configure which classes you want your script to be able to access](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-security.html).

To be able to make logging work in scripts I have defined my own policy file and set it JAVA_OPTS or even in the startup command as `-Djava.security.policy=file:///D:/ES/elasticsearch-2.3.1/my.policy`. The **minimum** content of the `my.policy` file should be:

```
grant {
    permission org.elasticsearch.script.ClassPermission "org.elasticsearch.common.logging.*";
    permission org.elasticsearch.script.ClassPermission "org.apache.log4j.*";
};
```

Of course, you need to restart ES for the changes to be effective.

Comment: Is this still working for ES 6.3? 
I've edited directly the grant permissions in /modules/lang-painless/plugin-security.policy, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: It's very likely not to work in such a distant version. There are many versions inbetween.