# How I can emit logs from my groovy script

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, elasticsearch-5

Is there any way to emit logs from the elasticsearch stored script (groovy). I tried print, echo but then it didn't work out.

Please let me know if anyone has a solution.

Elasticsearch version: *5.1.1*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access logger from Elasticsearch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981832/access-logger-from-elasticsearch-script)

Comment: @SoumyaKanti the link you posted has nothing to do with the question OP asked. How this question can be enhaced? Coming here from google, this question is very clear, trying to output logs from a groovy script. I don't see the point of your comment. If you don't understand it, it doesn't mean it's wrong.